# change image and sidebar

Tags: html, css, tabview

I am trying to acquire the look and feel of a drop down menu with a mouse click. 
The html I have so far looks a bit like this

```
<div id="tabs">
<ul id="tab_list">
    <li><a href="" id="tab1" class="active">Contents</a></li>
    <li><a href="" id="tab1" class="active">Contents</a></li>
    <li><a href="" id="tab1" class="active">Contents</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div id="tab_contents">
<div class="">
<h2>The table of contents</h2>
<p>The descriptive text for this tab</p>
</div>
<div class="hide">
<h2>About the author</h2>
</div>
<div class="hide">
<h2>About the downloads</h2>
</div>
</div>
```

And the css

```
#tabs{margin-top: 1em;} 
#tab_list{margin: 0;
          padding: 3px 6px;
          border-bottom: 1px solid black;}            
#tab_list li {list-style-type: none;
              display: inline;}               
#tab_list li a {padding: 3px 1em;
                margin-left: 3px;
                text-decoration: none;
                font-weight: bold;
                color: black;
                background: yellow;
                border: 1px solid black;
                border-bottom: none;}                   
#tab_list li a:hover{background: white;
                    border-color: black;}                       
#tab_list li a:active{background-color: white;
                      border-bottom: 1px solid white;}                        
#tab_contents div{padding: 5px 10px 10px;
                  border: 1px solid black;
                  border-top: 0;
                  height: 100px;}                     
.hide {display: none;}
```

Now i want to hide and show each content page based on the category i choose.
How can i acquire this effect? Please, work directly in my example.

Comment: Could you edit the mark-up to better show what `tab` relates to what content (possibly edit the `contents` string to clarify), also your HTML is invalid: an `id` ***must*** be unique within the document. And, possibly, show an image that explains what you want.

Comment: @DavidThomas right i will fix the id and classes, i created a jsfiddle for it so check it out http://jsfiddle.net/jrhuW/

Comment: Thanks! And are you able to change the mark-up around at all? And...do you want an accordion type menu, or a paged-tabs type menu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understood correctly what you want, I'm not sure it can be done without js and why do you have  tags with the same id ?